# Why does my sequelize query break with ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR when eager loading a model associated to another with belongsTo/hasMany?

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, database-design, sequelize.js

## Sequelize version:

4.37.10

## Model definitions:

### LocalChapters.js

```
const Database = require('./database');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const NationalChapters = require('./nationalchapters');

const LocalChapters = Database
.getInstance()
.define('localchapters', {
    idLocalChapter: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER(11),
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        unique: true
    },
    LocalName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(45),
        allowNull: false
    }
}, {
    timestamps: false
});

LocalChapters.belongsTo(NationalChapters, { foreignKey: 'NationalChapter_id', onDelete: 'CASCADE' });
NationalChapters.hasMany(LocalChapters);

module.exports = LocalChapters;
```

### NationalChapters.js

```
const Database = require('./database');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const NationalChapters = Database
.getInstance()
.define('nationalchapters', {
    idNationalChapter: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER(11),
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        unique: true
    },
    NationalName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(45),
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true
    }
}, {
    timestamps: false
});

module.exports = NationalChapters;
```

## Query ran:

```
const result = await NationalChapters.findAll({
    include: [ LocalChapters ]
});
```

## Expected result:

```
[
  {
    idNationalChapter: 21,
    NationalName: 'Some National Chapter Name',
    localchapters: [
      {
        idLocalChapter: 15,
        LocalName: 'Some Local Chapter Name'
      },
      ...
    ]
  }
  ...
]
```

## Error received:

```
DatabaseError [SequelizeDatabaseError]: Unknown column 'localchapters.nationalchapterIdNationalChapter' in 'field list'
    at Query.formatError (/<file path>/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/query.js:247:16)
    at Query.handler [as onResult] (/<file path>/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/query.js:68:23)
    at Query.Command.execute (/<file path>/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/command.js:30:12)
    at Connection.handlePacket (/<file path>/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:502:28)
    at PacketParser.onPacket (/<file path>/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:81:16)
    at PacketParser.executeStart (/<file path>/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packet_parser.js:77:14)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/<file path>/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:89:29)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:308:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:289:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:223:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:182:23) {
  name: 'SequelizeDatabaseError',
  parent: Error: Unknown column 'localchapters.nationalchapterIdNationalChapter' in 'field list'
      at Packet.asError (/<file path>/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packets/packet.js:716:13)
      at Query.Command.execute (/<file path>/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/command.js:28:22)
      at Connection.handlePacket (/<file path>/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:502:28)
      at PacketParser.onPacket (/<file path>/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:81:16)
      at PacketParser.executeStart (/<file path>/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packet_parser.js:77:14)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (/<file path>/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:89:29)
      at Socket.emit (events.js:210:5)
      at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:308:12)
      at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:289:11)
      at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:223:10)
      at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:182:23) {
    code: 'ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR',
    errno: 1054,
    sqlState: '42S22',
    sqlMessage: "Unknown column 'localchapters.nationalchapterIdNationalChapter' in 'field list'",
    sql: 'SELECT `nationalchapters`.`idNationalChapter`, 
                `nationalchapters`.`NationalName`, 
                `localchapters`.`idLocalChapter` AS `localchapters.idLocalChapter`, 
                `localchapters`.`LocalName` AS `localchapters.LocalName`, 
                `localchapters`.`NationalChapter_id` AS `localchapters.NationalChapter_id`, 
                `localchapters`.`nationalchapterIdNationalChapter` AS `localchapters.nationalchapterIdNationalChapter` 
            FROM `nationalchapters` AS `nationalchapters` 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN `localchapters` AS `localchapters` 
            ON `nationalchapters`.`idNationalChapter` = `localchapters`.`nationalchapterIdNationalChapter`;'
  },
  original: Error: Unknown column 'localchapters.nationalchapterIdNationalChapter' in 'field list'
      at Packet.asError (/<file path>/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packets/packet.js:716:13)
      at Query.Command.execute (/<file path>/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/command.js:28:22)
      at Connection.handlePacket (/<file path>/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:502:28)
      at PacketParser.onPacket (/<file path>/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:81:16)
      at PacketParser.executeStart (/<file path>/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packet_parser.js:77:14)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (/<file path>/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:89:29)
      at Socket.emit (events.js:210:5)
      at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:308:12)
      at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:289:11)
      at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:223:10)
      at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:182:23) {
    code: 'ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR',
    errno: 1054,
    sqlState: '42S22',
    sqlMessage: "Unknown column 'localchapters.nationalchapterIdNationalChapter' in 'field list'",
    sql: 'SELECT `nationalchapters`.`idNationalChapter`, 
                `nationalchapters`.`NationalName`, 
                `localchapters`.`idLocalChapter` AS `localchapters.idLocalChapter`, 
                `localchapters`.`LocalName` AS `localchapters.LocalName`, 
                `localchapters`.`NationalChapter_id` AS `localchapters.NationalChapter_id`, 
                `localchapters`.`nationalchapterIdNationalChapter` AS `localchapters.nationalchapterIdNationalChapter` 
            FROM `nationalchapters` AS `nationalchapters` 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN `localchapters` AS `localchapters` 
            ON `nationalchapters`.`idNationalChapter` = `localchapters`.`nationalchapterIdNationalChapter`;'
  },
  sql: 'SELECT `nationalchapters`.`idNationalChapter`, 
                `nationalchapters`.`NationalName`, 
                `localchapters`.`idLocalChapter` AS `localchapters.idLocalChapter`, 
                `localchapters`.`LocalName` AS `localchapters.LocalName`, 
                `localchapters`.`NationalChapter_id` AS `localchapters.NationalChapter_id`, 
                `localchapters`.`nationalchapterIdNationalChapter` AS `localchapters.nationalchapterIdNationalChapter` 
            FROM `nationalchapters` AS `nationalchapters` 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN `localchapters` AS `localchapters` 
            ON `nationalchapters`.`idNationalChapter` = `localchapters`.`nationalchapterIdNationalChapter`;'
}
```

## Where I've landed:

This seems like a basic belongsTo/hasMany relationship that is generating broken SQL, yet I can't for the life of me figure out where I'm going wrong... Any ideas?

---

*Edits:*
- Fixed typo for model name in "Query ran" section

Answer (score 0):

**Resolved**

When creating a one-to-many association between models ***with a custom foreign key***, apparently you must specify the foreign key configuration in **both** the `belongsTo` and `hasMany` associations (not just one of them) like so:

```
LocalChapters.belongsTo(NationalChapters, { foreignKey: 'NationalChapter_id', onDelete: 'CASCADE' });
NationalChapters.hasMany(LocalChapters, { foreignKey: 'NationalChapter_id', onDelete: 'CASCADE' });
```

Hope this helps.